# .vimrc file does not apply after restarting

Tags: vim

I am new to vim, and I want to set the default color theme to obsidian2 (I have already put it into /colors).

In the normal mode, I enter `:e $MYVIMRC` to open the .vimrc file.

Then I add `:colorscheme obsidian2` into the .vimrc file.

After restarting vim, the default color theme does not change.

Any suggestions please?

**Edit:** I am using MacVim.  I also tried setting the `$MYGVIMRC`, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `:colorscheme obsidian2`, you just change the scheme temporarily.
If you want to change scheme permanently, add config like this in your vimrc file:

```
set background=dark
colorscheme obsidian2
```

then reload vimrc.

Answer (score 0):

If you instert `:colorscheme obsidian2` to .vimrc file, it's wrong.

You should remove `:` character like:
`colorscheme obsidian2`
and restart vim or run `:source %`

Comment: Prefixing command with `:` is fine. You can use as many `:`s as you like; `::::::colorscheme obsidian2` also works.